# How to higlight a search word

Tags: android, listview, search-engine, highlight

I am creating a search engine like application in android and i want to know how to highlight the searched word in a listview like in this link.. http://androidbible.blogspot.com/2010/12/color-highlight-and-whole-word-search.html thank you in advance for those who want to help...

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

Just a demo below.

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    SpannableString str = new SpannableString("hello");
    BackgroundColorSpan span = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);
    str.setSpan(span, 0, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    tv.setText(str);
```